# from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to X: understanding list initialization in constructors

Tags: c++, std-pair, list-initialization, stdinitializerlist, braced-init-list

It seems I don't understand braced init lists at all. Why does the following compile for operator=() (`entity e`) but not for the constructor (`entity f`)?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%0Astruct+entity%0A%7B%0A++++using+keyval_t+%3D+std::pair%3Cstd::string_view,+std::string_view%3E%3B%0A%0A++++entity()+%3D+default%3B%0A%0A++++entity(keyval_t+keyval)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22our+special+ctor+called!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++auto+operator%3D(keyval_t+keyval)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22our+special+operator+called!!%5Cn%22)%3B+++%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++entity+e%3B%0A++++//+entity+f+%3D+%7B+%22Hello%22,+%22World%22%7D%3B%0A%0A++++e+%3D+%7B+%22Hello%22,+%22World%22+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
#include <string_view>

struct entity
{
    using keyval_t = std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>;

    entity() = default;

    entity(keyval_t keyval) {
        printf("our special ctor called!\n");
    }

    auto operator=(keyval_t keyval) {
        printf("our special operator called!\n");   
    }
};

int main()
{
    entity e;
    // entity f = { "Hello", "World"}; <-- doesn't work??

    e = { "Hello", "World" };
}
```

**Bonus question**: How do I make it work in both cases?

Comment: FYI: `entity f = { { "Hello", "World" } };` works. (Your argument in 2nd constructor is a `std::pair`.) [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qMzssq9f3)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Ok but why does it work like this in the operator=() case? What's different?

Comment: The one is initialization, the other is assignment. (Sorry, initialization is a topic I myself still struggle with to understand thoroughly...) ;-)

Comment: `e` works because you're constructing `keyval_t` on the right hand side then calling your assignment operator. `f` doesn't use the assignment operator

Comment: A constructor creates a new object, while assignment modifies an existing object.  Your `f` example is attempting **construction**, even though you have chosen a syntax that uses the `=` character.

Comment: @DrewDormann I understand that f constructs the object, otherwise this demo would be kind of pointless. I do not understand however why e and f seem to disagree on the allowed conversion sequence to pick from. Maybe someone speaks standardese well enouth to explain this to me :/

Comment: @glades `entity f = {...};` is `entity f = f{...};` is `entity f = f(...);` is `entity f{...};` is `entity f(...);`. This is the standard.

Comment: To second @glades: With `struct Test { Test(int) { } };`, `Test test1 = { 1 };` works as well as `Test test2 = 2;`. Or is it _the_ difference that I used `int` instead of `std::pair`? ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dfd56a7eb323cdd))

Comment: As best I can determine, you have noticed that construction and assignment can have similar looking syntax.  And you are asking why they don't have identical syntax.  Your `f` example is trying to construct an entity from two strings.  And you have not written a constructor that accepts two strings.

Comment: @273K That finally makes sense. So the perspective of the compiler for what a brace-init list will be used for differs from assignement to constructor. In the later case the compiler will never try to interpret a brace init list as a single object but rather as a list for the constructors parameter list. operator=() expects one parameter thus the compiler can assume that a brace init list will represent one object. AHA! Rereading your updated answer made that clear as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::pair` has two member variables, thus two given values should be passes to.

This works

```
entity f = { {"Hello", "World"} };
             ^________________^  
                 keyval_t
           ^____________________^
          entity::entity(keyval_t)
```

`entity f = { "Hello", "World"};` implies calling a constructor with 2 parameters, that `entity` does not have. Same as `entity f{"Hello", "World"};` or `entity f("Hello", "World");`.

`e = { "Hello", "World" };` is just `operator=(keyval_t)` call with a `keyval_t{"Hello", "World"}`, since `keyval_t` has a constructor with 2 parameters.